# How to Match Data between two indexes in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, logstash, match

I've got two indexes one with customer data and the other with netflow.

I want to match the data while  entering to the netflow index and match it with other index, if there is a match I want to mutate the data and add the customer id.

I tried using logstash but nothing works ok :|

any ideas?
Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

Logstash looks to be the best strategy.

You can use a logstash **input** to read your netflow index (or use logstash to ingest your netflow directly)

Then in an elasticsearch **filter** you will query your customer index, find the good customer document, and add the data on your netflow event.

In an elasticsearch **output**, you update (or ingest) your enhanced netflow document.

I use this strategy for data fixes and data enhancement, when a enrich processor is not the good strategy.

Comment: i tried using the elastic search filter but i got this error 

[WARN ] 2020-10-02 19:23:09.536 [[main]>worker2] elasticsearch - Failed to query elasticsearch for previous event {:index=>"logstash-*", :error=>"Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n

if i export the data as a json could i match anything?

Comment: could you add you elasticsearch filter configuration please. The message has to do with the query you use